Conditional sequence of events
1 When I come she plays
2 When I come she is playing
1 she start playing after I come and 2 she start playing before I come
3 When I am hungry she is making me sandwiches
To me 3 is ok and means that she makes sandwiches during the time when I'm hungry not before. Is my thinking correct?

Related. Sequence of actions

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This has nothing to do with the conditional.
(1) would be better expressed as "When I come/arrive, she starts to play." Your version would probably be understood to mean "She plays every time I come."
There is no reason to use the continuous tense in (3). 'She' presumably doesn't spend all the time that you are feeling hungry in making sandwiches. "Whenever I am hungry she makes me sandwiches" would sound more natural.

I mean "If I'm cooking she is sleeping" this sentence is fine. Both happens at the same time.  With my 3 example I wanted to make something similar but it's not possibly to make "when I'm hungry " continuous or I think I could add "being hungry". What do you think?

"If I'm cooking she is sleeping"?? Do you really mean "Whenever I start cooking she immediately falls asleep"? Who says it's 'fine'? And what's wrong with "When I'm feeling hungry..."?
